# How many text corpus is minimally needed for LDA Topic Modelling?

Tags: nlp, lda

I am a beginner in NLP and I am recently considering the possibility of applying **LDA Topic Modelling** to **Ancient Chinese Poems**.

I am consider how many poems would I need to feed into the model to have a relatively good performance if possible. Can anyone gives some suggestion? I know it's a bit vague, but I just want to have a rough idea about it.

Comment: I am looking at this dataset: https://github.com/chinese-poetry/chinese-poetry/tree/master/json

Comment: It has 50K poems. Would that be possibly enough?